# Angular 8 Printing the Html

Tags: angular, angular8, production-environment

I have simple angular 8 application, and I am printing some html part in my angular component which is working fine in development build, but if I deploy my angular application on production build the print document open and then closes immediately, so I can't view, print or save my document.

I have tried my different methods to print but the case is simple that on production build it's not working.

typescript method which I am using

```
    print(): void {
       let printContents, popupWin;
       printContents = document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML;
       popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 
       'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
       popupWin.document.open();
       popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
      <head>
          <title>${this.printTitle}</title>
          <style></style>
      </head>
      <body onload="window.print();window.close()">
        ${printContents}
      </body>
      </html>
     `);
    }
```

Comment: i thnk this is due to your site settings. in your site settings popup's and redirects is blocked by default. try to enable and try again.

Comment: window.print();window.close() I think this is what is opening and closing your window

Comment: @FarhatZaman you are right i actually messed up with chrome settings so that's why its not showing the popup window.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('invoice').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', 'my_print', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.write(`
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>${this.printTitle}</title>
    <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    ${printContents}
    </body>
    </html>
    `);
    popupWin.print();
    popupWin.close();
}
```